# How to rename figure legend in ggplot? aes gives length error

Tags: r, ggplot2, rename, facet-grid

I'm new to using R and I've run into a problem.

I've made a scatterplot using `geom_point`.

[image: scatterplot]

I've managed to rename the facet grid labels, but I don't know how to rename the figure legend. I've tried renaming the line `geom_point(aes(colour = Diet))` to `geom_point(aes(colour = diet_names))` but the following error occurs:

`Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (23): colour.`

If I remove all but one of the values below (E.g. just leaving in fish_or = "Fish") the error doesn't occur, but obviously I don't want just one coloured value on the table.

```
    diet_names <- c(
      fish_or = "Fish" ,
      fruit_pu = "Fruit" ,
      insects_nectar_bl = "Insects & Nectar" ,
      insects_re = "Insects" ,
      seeds_gr = "Seeds")
```

I'd like to edit the legend into something more clear as it's data for a poster I'm making. Thanks :)

Full code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
Birdbeaks <- read.csv("Birdbeaks.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

diet_names <- c(
fish_or = "Fish" ,
fruit_pu = "Fruit" ,
insects_nectar_bl = "Insects & Nectar" ,
insects_re = "Insects" ,
seeds_gr = "Seeds") 

ggplot(Birdbeaks, aes(bill_lengthavg, bill_depthavg)) +
geom_point(aes(colour = diet)) +
labs(x = "Bill Length(cm)", y = "Bill Depth(cm)", colour = "Diet")+ 
guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 5))) +
theme_update()+
facet_grid(~diet, scales="fixed", labeller = as_labeller(diet_names))
```

Comment: Anything in `aes` should generally be bare names of columns in the data being used. Make a variable in the data that brings in those diet values

Comment: You can also change labels with the `labels` argument to your color scale

Comment: I'd usually just have edited the csv itself to simplify things for me, but as it's part of an assignment I'd like to stick to using R as much as I can. Is there a way I can add a variable using R itself?

Comment: There are lots of ways to add a column to a data frame, and any tutorial on getting started in R should show you how. Since we don't have a sample of your data, we can't help with that specifically—it's unclear whether you'd want to add a vector as a column in the data frame, or if you need to do a merge/join, or change factor levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is useful

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

    Birdbeaks %>%
      mutate(diet = case_when(
        diet == "fish_or" ~ "Fish",
        diet == "fruit_pu" ~ "Fruit",
        diet == "insects_nectar_bl" ~ "Insects & Nectar",
        diet == "insects_re" ~ "Insects",
        diet == "seeds_gr" ~ "Seeds"
      )) %>%
      ggplot(aes(bill_lengthavg, bill_depthavg)) +
        geom_point(aes(colour = diet)) +
        labs(x = "Bill Length(cm)", y = "Bill Depth(cm)", colour = "Diet") +
        guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 5))) +
        theme_update() +
        facet_grid(~diet, scales = "fixed")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I've used the mutation function a tiny bit in the past, is it moreorless a direct  replacement function?

Comment: Exactly. in this case, because the new column to create has the same name as the existing column `diet`, it replaces the values of `diet ` with the values generated by `case_when`. Btw, welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. Is the pipes function in this case effectively loading the 'Birdbeaks' file, then while it's still open mutating it and while it's still mutated then creating a graph? I've been trying to wrap my head around the %>%, but does it effectively save me time by not requiring me to make `<-` object names and implementing them in independent commands?                         Sorry for the additional question, but I think this will help me a lot going forward! Thanks for the welcome and super fast response!

Comment: The pipe operator places the result of the previous block of code as the first argument of the function after it. For example, instead of data <- function_a(data); data2 <- function_b(data); data3 <- function_c(data2), you can simply do: data_new <- data %>% function_a() %>% function_b() %>% function_c(). Also, it does not modifies the stored data object unless the result is assigned. More info here: https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks once more :)